# bitmap To Mat , the came out Mat is null

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, mat

I'm try using MatchTemplate on camera view , but when I try convert bitmap back to mat , the output mat is null , and is no error .

```
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();      


        if(Template != null){

            Imgproc.matchTemplate(mRgba, Template, mRgba, Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF);
            Core.putText(mRgba, "Matching", new Point(50, 50), BIND_AUTO_CREATE, BIND_AUTO_CREATE, Color_Green, 2);
        }   
    return mRgba;
    }  
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Mat tmp = new Mat (100, 100, CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(4));
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2mRGBA, 0);
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmp);
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, mRgba.cols()/2-50, mRgba.rows()/2-50, 100, 100, null, false);

        //show for debug            
        ImageView Img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);                   
        Img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        Bitmap matbitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(matbitmap, Template);//the output Template is null,so that I can't do next work 

        return false;
        }
```

Comment: Can you add some declaration for Template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the Template.

```
Mat Template= new Mat();
```

Then you can use it. Also I would expect `Utils.bitmapToMat` to throw exception for `Template = null` but this is a different story...

Comment: The `Template` is not null anymore, but `Imgproc.matchTemplate(mRgba, Template, mRgba, Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF);` is go for another error,
Thank yot for the help anway